# Anyone know what this flower is?

Tags: identification, flowers

Growing in October, the weather is warm; this is in the Northwest Georgia area.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it is Antirrhinum (Snapdragons). Maybe a wild variant?

Comment: I will check that out! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I found it. Its a Wishbone Flower.

Answer (score 8):

Its a Wishbone Flower. I found it after searching for about an hour.

Comment: Yes, you found it! _Torenia fournieri_ 'Kauai Rose', very nice flower!